# Karate print json with embedded expression in it

Tags: karate

print doesn't work well with embedded expression when it has ^^ in it. How to make this to print the actual value after replacement?

```
* def x = [{x: 'x1'}, {x: 'x2'}]
* def y = {y: '#(^^x)'}
* print y
```

this will print

```
{y: '#(^^x)'}
```

but what i want to print is

```
{y: [{x: 'x1'}, {x: 'x2'}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be badly confused. The `^^` short-cuts are designed for using in `match` statements.

Do this normally and you will get what you expect:

```
* def y = { y: '#(x)' }
* print y
```

Comment: im not sure what do you mean split into 2 step. example?